# what is an easy way to duplicate a "write form fields to database" process?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, sql

I have an ASP.net (C#) application that I am working on. In the application are multiple pages of form fields to be filled out and submitted. At the bottom of the last page is a submit button which writes everything to the databse. The code for writing these fields from form to DB is very complex as there are about 30 different stored procedures being called. I am trying to create a duplicate when a user clicks on a new button called "replicate", which SHOULD store a duplicate copy in the DB. I try to copy paste the code for write to DB from the "submit" button but I get a bunch of problems. I have tried a lot of different approaches such as pasting the submit button's code in a new method and from the "replicate" button call that method but this approach doesn't work. So, I am confused as to whether there is an easier way to duplicate the submitted copy that is being stored in the DB. Normally a couple SQL statements would work but in this case there are about 35 stored procedures, 70 SQL tables, and 425 columns, which is a problem.

So basically a summary of the problem is:

I have a form that on submit, writes the filled fields into various locations in the DB, depending on what the field is.

I would like to create a "replicate" button that duplicates the DB stored fields of the form creating a duplicate copy.

Issue: As I stated there are about 215 form fields and 70 SQL tables, each form field going into a certain column in the table.

Comment: by copy, do you mean that you are going to insert the values two times into your database? or are you saving the copy somewhere else..?

Comment: say form 1 is open (form 1 is stored in DB and since the user decided to open form 1 the application loads form 1's filled out fields from DB), and user clicks replicate, then the stored form's fields are replicated meaning inserted into the DB AGAIN so now you have duplicate entries in the DB for all the form fields (ofcourse I have given all the entries a unique id so despite the duplicate entries, a person may distinguish original from duplicate.

Comment: The code for the "submit" button: is that code to **update** or **insert** a record? From your answer it seems the button does an **update**

Comment: you are correct, "submit" button updates the DB, there are sub buttons along subsections of the form which insert the fields to the DB; however, switching tabs from one subsection to another subsection also writes the fields to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

I would go about this by creating one more stored procedure which does the copying directly in the database. Then you could have your "Replicate" button call the new stored procedure which creates the copy and returns some handle (some base id value created for the copy) and use the handle to load the copied version into the application. Make sure to run the copying inside a transaction so you either get a complete copy to commit or can rollback if some error occurred.